# Putting tar paper between plywood subfloor/underlayment and decking in kitchen

Tags: repair, flooring, subfloor

We are preparing to put new sheet vinyl down in a kitchen.  We tore out the old subfloor and replaced it with new plywood. Is there any benefit to putting tar paper down between the floor decking and plywood subfloor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its an additional vapor barrier and could prevent underlayment from warping. In a bathroom its always a good idea to do to keep moisture away from subfloor.